# how to create an UI component that support stylus pen that overlay a non editable text?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to create a UI that allow taking note (as drawing with stylus pen) over some text like you take note on your text book. What component in compose that support stylus pen (drawing mode) that can overlay a none editable text?

I am new to kotlin compose and confuse between different classes of Canvas. Not sure there is out of the box support for drawing stylus pen